# Safari jquery ajax request returns 304 Not Modified on page refreshed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, safari

I have a simple ajax request inside $(window).load() that runs automatically; Everything works perfectly in all browsers except Safari.

In safari, if I refresh the page manually the request returns 304 Not Modified.

**I've tried:**

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
type:'POST', headers: {"cache-control":"no-cache"}, cache: false
});
```

**and:**

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST', 
  cache: false,
  url: 'test.php?x='+y+'&nocache=' + new Date().getTime(), 
  etc
```

**Also:**

```
Setting cache, expires etc headers on test.php
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be happening at all due to it being a post request. You shouldn't need to do any cache-control to make it not cache. Are you actually sending any post params with the request?

Comment: Yes, sending params and their being included too. It's worth noting the images and external stylesheets are also showing 304. I'm simply reloading the page and the 304 messages arise.